# If a 2x2 matrix multiplied with a column matrix outputs the transform of that column matrix, what does 2x2 matrix multiplied with 2x2 matrix output?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3\\\ 5 & 6\end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix} $$

I have just recently started to learn matrices so I apologize if I make any mistakes explaining my question.

A 2x2 matrix like the one above I learnt represents the linear transform of some vectors (the second matrix above x and y) when its multiplied with the second matrix. I sort of understand how this works.

Since a 2d vector can be represented as **x* $\widehat{i}$ + y* $\widehat{j}$, basically saying 'go x times to the right and y times up', with the transformed matrix, im saying 'go 4x times to the right and 11y times up, that will be your transformed vector'

But in the case of something like, $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3\\\ 5 & 6\end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix}x & x1 \\ y & y1 \end{pmatrix} $$

x and y is a vector right? and x1 and y1 is a second set of vectors right? So here im  using $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3\\ 5 & 6\end{pmatrix} to transform these vectors and return me two transformed vectors rather than just one previously

But that leaves me confused. Does that mean even $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3\\\ 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}$$ is just 2 vectors? And if those 2 vectors are considered a transform, does that mean even $$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix} $$ is a transform too? Any and all matrices are transforms, thus if any and all matrices represent a vector, all vectors are transforms by that logic? Which brings to my question...

**...So a matrix-matrix multiplication is just a transform multiplied by a transform?** Im not able to wrap my head around that idea that every matrix multiplication with another matrix is just 2 transforms multiplied by each other.

I apologize if my formatting for the matrices was not correct, I do not know how to get them to have straight brackets as im new to this kind of formatting

Comment: Matrices are both transformations and vectors. Typically the distinction is made depending on how you use them. I interpret these linguistically as the difference between the noun and the verb form respectively. Some words are both nouns and verbs such as to go for a swim is a noun and to swim is a verb. it's a subtle but useful distinction.

Comment: @CyclotomicField So are they both transforms and vectors at the same time or are they only one of them at any given time based on the 'context' of what we are doing with them?

Comment: They're both at the same time but context will determine what you're doing with them. You can also think of them as transformations transforming another transformation in the same way that given two functions you can define a new function as their composition. In fact the composition of linear transformations as functions turns out to be matrix multiplication with respect to some basis.

Comment: @CyclotomicField So if i multiply a 2x2 vector matrix with some other matrix, im transforming that other matrix with respect to the basis? And in this case the basis vectors are the vectors in the initial 2x2 matrix?

Comment: The basis will determine the entries of the matrix in the first place and this will almost always be the canonical basis vectors. For a $2 \times 2$ matrix this would be the four matrices with a single $1$ and every other entry $0$. You can then decompose the matrix in terms of these basis vectors as $\sum_{k=1}^4 = \lambda_k e_k$ with $\lambda_k$ a scalar and $e_k$ the basis vectors to see how the transformation acts on them independently. You can also reverse this letting the latter matrix act on the former as the distinction between object and action is arbitrary.

Comment: @CyclotomicField What exactly does 'you can then decompose the matrix in terms of these basis vectors as ∑4k=1=λkek with λk a scalar and ek the basis vectors to see how the transformation acts on them independently. You can also reverse this letting the latter matrix act on the former as the distinction between object and action is arbitrary.' mean?

Comment: I don't know how else to express that more simply. If you're not familiar with basis vectors and linear combinations you're going to struggle with interpreting matrix multiplication.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I understand what basis vectors are but the part of 'transformation acting on them independetly' is what got me confused. Here the transformation is done on a vector and 'them' refers to the vector being transformed right?

'You can also reverse this letting the latter matrix act on the former as the distinction between object and action is arbitrary.' '

I am confused here because I thought if you have 2 matrices A and B, AB is not always equal to B? So if we reverse it wont the result change?

Sorry I shouldve made my previous comment more precise